# To get a specific record from list of multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

My table has data as below:

```
Column1    Column2   Column3  
ACC1        940       1  
ACC1        950       1     
ACC1        950       50  
ACC2        940       1  
ACC2        950       50  
ACC3        940       1  
ACC4        950       1  
ACC5        950       50
```

My expectation is to retrieve unique record w.r.t column1.
condition 1: if only one account record there, retrieve it.
condition 2: if multiple records are there for a given account and among them
           only one record having column 3 value as 50, retrieve this 50 value
          record

Comment: And if neither of those conditions are met, then which record?

Comment: please show us what you have tried and also required output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get one record per `column1` value, then this is a prioritization query.  One method is using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1
                                order by column3 desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

If this is a filtering query, where you want either singleton records or records with a value greater than 50, then window functions can still be used:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by column1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 or column3 >= 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT column1, 
                          Count(DISTINCT column1) AS count1 
                   FROM   table 
                   GROUP  BY column1) X 
               ON t1.column1 = X.column1 
WHERE  x.count1 = 1
```

Comment: Where did you handled condition 2 here?

Comment: 50 is the max value, so seq num 1 will retrieve the 1st record 50. I have other task in the same query where if multiple records with value 50 are there we have more conditions. Will work on that. Thank you.

Comment: AND t1.column3 >=50